How to create a plotly graph in Power BI
I'm using the Python visual tool for Power BI and I would like to create a plotly graph, like in this video
I'm able to create plots with seaborn and matplotlib, but when I try plotly it gives the error:

But it works because it opens the graph in a html window, outside Power BI.
What Am I doing wrong?
This is the code used in Power BI Python visual:
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go  # Import go for graph_objects

# Create a scatter plot figure
fig = go.Figure()

# Add scatter trace
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=dataset['I_B'], 
        y=dataset['I_C'],
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(size=8, color='blue', opacity=0.7)
    )
)

# Customize the layout
fig.update_layout(
    title="Scatter Plot of I_B vs. I_C",
    xaxis_title="I_B",
    yaxis_title="I_C",
    width=800,
    height=500,
    template="plotly_white"
)

# Show the figure inline
fig.show()


In Python visual tool in Power BI, output display is not fully compatible with Plotly's interactive visualizations.
that is why Plotly typically tries to open the plot in an external HTML window, which is not you requiremnt.
you can try the plotly.io library to convert your figure to a static image format compatible with Power BI. try below code
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go  # Import go for graph_objects
import plotly.io as pio  # Import plotly.io for static image rendering

 
fig = go.Figure()

 
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=dataset['I_B'], 
        y=dataset['I_C'],
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(size=8, color='blue', opacity=0.7)
    )
)

 
fig.update_layout(
    title="Scatter Plot of I_B vs. I_C",
    xaxis_title="I_B",
    yaxis_title="I_C",
    width=800,
    height=500,
    template="plotly_white"
)

 
img_bytes = pio.to_image(fig, format='png')

 
from IPython.display import Image
Image(img_bytes)


Thank you for the response; I understand. However, the goal is to have an interactive plot. Converting it to a static one falls outside the intended scope—otherwise, I would simply use matplotlib or seaborn.

I got you..
1)Either You can use Plotly Dash to create a web-based interactive dashboard that you can host and then embed in Power BI as a web content element.
I mean,deploy your Dash app to a web server (e.g.Azure) and embedding the app’s URL in Power BI using a Web Content visual.

2)Or,You can try integrating plotly-resampler, which optimizes Plotly's interactive functionality for larger datasets by downsampling it.
Plotly-resampler may work directly in Power BI's Python visual as per documentation, as it uses plotly objects and aims to improve interactivity performance within limited environments.
here is the link(please go through it:https://github.com/predict-idlab/plotly-resampler
However,If the need is be in Power BI only , interactive workaround with Plotly directly within Power BI may still be under development.

I am not sure,i just read it only that  second approach may or may not work directly in Power BI Python visuals, but if it does, plotly-resampler will optimize interactive rendering within Power BI’s limited environment.so give it a try

Here is just a sample code using the same github link...try this out too..
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly_resampler import FigureResampler

# Sample data
data = {
    'I_B': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'I_C': [10, 14, 18, 25, 30, 35]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a scatter plot figure using FigureResampler
fig = FigureResampler(go.Figure())

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df['I_B'], 
        y=df['I_C'],
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(size=8, color='blue', opacity=0.7)
    )
)

# Customize the layout
fig.update_layout(
    title="Scatter Plot of I_B vs. I_C",
    xaxis_title="I_B",
    yaxis_title="I_C",
    template="plotly_white"
)

# Show the figure inline
fig.show()

